# How do I consolidate unique row values into a single column across multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql

I'm performing a series of aggregations on a number of rows. I'm grouping by a common column, but I have minor fields that I want to consolidate all unique values into a single column.

The example below doesn't have the aggregate calculations to simplify the problem.

For instance:

```
Table A
  table_a_id integer,
  column_1 integer,
  column_2 text,
  column_3 integer

SELECT table_a_id, column1, column_2, column_3
FROM table_a;
```

Yields

```
101  |  1  | 'sample value 1'  | 20
101  |  2  | 'sample value 2'  | 25
101  |  3  | 'sample value 3'  | 27
```

I want:

```
101  | 1, 2, 3  | 'sample value 1, sample value 2, sample value 3'  | 20, 25, 27
```

How do I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  table_a_id,
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct column_1), ',') AS the_ones,
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct column_2), ',') AS the_twos,
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct column_3), ',') AS the_threes
from table_a 
group by table_a_id
;
```

Comment: As of Postgres 9.0, [there is a `string_agg` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) so `array_to_string(array_agg(foo, ','))` can be simplified to `string_agg(foo, ',')`.